# CI pipeline returns an error when running npm ci

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-actions

I have recently tried to add a `.yml` file for my React project, but the pipeline keeps on hitting an error when the build tries to run `npm ci`. This runs completely fine on my local machine but doesn't run on the pipeline for some reason. The code is [here](https://github.com/aheedshah/toddler-world), and the .yml file is [here](https://github.com/aheedshah/toddler-world/blob/main/.github/workflows/build_test_react.yml).

Some things I have tried:

- I thought the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are not in sync so I have tried to download `package-lock.json` again by deleting it first and running `npm install --package-lock-only` but still fails in [this PR](https://github.com/aheedshah/toddler-world/pull/23).
- Tried confining the Node version to the one in my machine to 18.x but it still fails

Below is my .yml file:

```yaml
name: Build and Test React Application

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  build_test:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 18.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: npm ci, build and test
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build --if-present
          npm test
      - name: Upload coverage reports to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3
        env:
          CODECOV_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
```

and here is the debug code:

```
Run npm ci
  npm ci
  npm run build --if-present
  npm test
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's ajv@6.12.6 does not satisfy ajv@8.12.0
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 does not satisfy json-schema-traverse@1.0.0
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: typescript@4.9.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit]
npm ERR! [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-10-04T21_35_18_017Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Does anyone have any idea of what to do or anything to do differently?

Comment: If you can successfully run `npm ci` locally, and your `git status` shows no uncommitted changes in the package or lock files, then it should run just the same in CI.

Comment: That's what's weird. Ran npm ci locally, no issues except a few warnings. Clean working tree, no commits. Any obvious issues I might be overlooking?

Comment: Are those warnings at all related to the errors in CI? Do you have to `--force` any installs (or have any other local npm config that might be different in the pipeline)?

Comment: Nothing points out to CI directly. Mostly "PostCSS line return parsing warnings" or "Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check warnings". Don't have to force anything either and don't have any other local npm config either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran a dependabot on the code and after it made changes to `package-lock.json`, the pipeline worked fine!

Try running that if any of you have the same problem in the future!